# Accessing both parent and local methods in Light DOM

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to build an `<editable-list>` with Polymer 1.0

Ideally, I should be able to use it like so:

```
<user-list>
  <editable-list data="{{data}}">
    <template id="items">
      <h4>[[item.name]]</h4>
      <!-- isAuthorized() is a method in `user-list` -->
      <template is="dom-if" if="{{isAuthorized(item)}}">
        <span> - Is authorized</span>
      </template>
      <!-- deleteRow() is a method in `editable-list` -->
      <button on-tap="deleteRow"> Delete this row </button>
    </template>
  </editable-list>
<user-list>
```

**tl;dr**

The `<editable-list>`s Light DOM accesses 2 functions, one of which is contained in `<user-list>` and the other in `<editable-list>`. I can get either one *or* the other to be defined, but not both.

---

I've made this happen by using the Light Dom documentation to create elements that wrap content within them.

The problem I have is the following.

- In the above example, I'm calling a function via the `<dom-if>`, called `isAuthorized()`.
- `isAuthorized()` exists in the component that encapsulates the `<editable-list>` itself.

So naturally I got this error when I tried to run the above:

> compute method `isAuthorized` not defined

To mitigate this, I've rescoped the `repeater` so it uses the parent element methods, via setting the `dataHost` property

```
// Templatize Light DOM
const template = this.querySelector("#items");
this.$.repeater.templatize(template);
Polymer.Bind.prepareModel(this.$.repeater);
Polymer.Base.prepareModelNotifyPath(this.$.repeater);

// Rescope the repeated Light DOM to point to the parent
var dataHost = (this.dataHost && this.dataHost._rootDataHost) || this.dataHost;
this.$.repeater.dataHost = dataHost;
```

#### New issues after rescoping:

- The delete button I have in `<editable-list>` calls a function that exists in `<editable-list>`.
- The `dataHost` rescoping I did prevents me from accessing this method since I only have access to the encapsulating element's (parent) methods.

Is there any way to go around this problem? Like a way to "merge" the methods of `<editable-list>` and parent element so I can use both elements method from the Light DOM?

---

#### Editable List Component:

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="editable-list">
  <template>
    <content></content>
    <template is="dom-repeat" id="repeater" items="{{data}}"></template>
  </template>
  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      "use strict";

      Polymer({

        is: "editable-list",
        
        ready: function() {
          const template = this.querySelector("#items");
          this.$.repeater.templatize(template);
          Polymer.Bind.prepareModel(this.$.repeater);
          Polymer.Base.prepareModelNotifyPath(this.$.repeater);
        },
        
        deleteRow: function() {
          alert("assume this row is deleted")
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<user-list></user-list>
```

#### User List Component (contains the editable list)

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">


<dom-module id="user-list">
  <template>
    <editable-list data="{{data}}">
      <template id="items">
        <h4>[[item.name]]</h4>
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isAuthorized(item)}}">
          <span> - Is authorized</span>
        </template>
        <button on-tap="deleteRow"> Delete this row </button>
      </template>
    </editable-list>
  </template>
  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      "use strict";

      Polymer({

        is: "user-list",
        properties: {
         data: {
           type: Array,
           value: [
            {
              name: "Foo",
              authorized: true
            },
            {
              name: "Bar",
              authorized: false
            }
           ]
         }
        },
        
        isAuthorized: function(user) {
          if (user.authorized) return true;
          else return false;
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>


<user-list></user-list>
```

Here's an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1259q4j/8/). Please note that it's not really working since `dataHost` seems to be undefined in JSFiddle. It might/or not give an overview of the code in any case